# Fine tuning table output of function 'univariateTable'

Tags: r, csv, rounding, export-to-csv

I've found the function `univariateTable` to be extremely helpful to handling larger data for a nice, clean table output. But there are a couple of things that I still need to do manually after the table is exported in `csv`, and I would rather do it in R to automate the process and avoid human errors.

Here is the example code with the table output that I then export as `csv`

```
value<-cbind(c(rnorm(103.251,503.24,90),rnorm(103.251,823.24,120)))
genotype<-cbind(c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))
gender<-rep(c("M","F","F","F"),50)
df<-cbind(value,genotype,gender)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("value","genotype","gender")
df$value<-as.numeric(as.character(df$value))
library(Publish)
summary(univariateTable(gender ~ Q(value) + genotype, data=df))
```

The two problems I have are these:

1. Is there a way to round the numbers in the table in a way similar to this: `round(99.73)`
2. Is there a way to substitute `,` with `-` in the interquartile range output in a way similar to this: `gsub(", ","-","[503.7, 793.3]")` , and instead of `median [iqr]` have it put out `median [IQR]`

Again, I do these manually after exporting the tables, but for larger tables it is much more convenient to automate the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`univariateTable` has a digits argument that you can use for rounding. To modify the formatting, you can inspect the list returned by `univariateTable` to figure out where to find the values that need to be changed.

Your example data threw an error, so I've modified it to make it run and also cleaned up the code a bit.

```
# devtools::install_github("tagteam/Publish")
library(Publish)

value <- c(rnorm(90, 103.251,503.24),rnorm(110, 103.251,823.24))
genotype <- rep(c("A","B"), each=100)
gender <- rep(c("M","F","F","F"),50)
df <- data.frame(value,genotype,gender)
```

The `digits` argument to `univariateTable` can be used for rounding (see `?univariateTable` for the help information on the function).

```
tab = univariateTable(gender ~ Q(value) + genotype, data=df, digits=0)
```

To change the commas to hyphens, we need to see where those values are stored in the list returned by `univariateTable`. Run `str(tab)`, which shows you the structure of the list. Note that the heading values in the table look like they're stored in `tab$summary.groups$value` and `tab$summary.totals$value`, so we'll edit those:

```
tab$summary.groups$value = gsub(", ", " - ", tab$summary.groups$value)
tab$summary.totals$value = gsub(", ", " - ", tab$summary.totals$value)

tab

  Variable        Level gender = F (n=150) gender = M (n=50)   Total (n=200) p-value
1    value median [iqr]    -6 [-481 - 424]  203 [-167 - 544] 80 [-433 - 458]   0.118
2 genotype            A            75 (50)           25 (50)        100 (50)        
3                     B            75 (50)           25 (50)        100 (50)   1.000
```

Comment: wow great solution. Would I replace `[iqr]` with `[IQR]` the same way?

Comment: Yes. Just figure out where it is in the list, and modify that list element.